# What's the difference between boost::static_pointer_cast vs boost::shared_static_cast?

Tags: boost

I'm reading through some legacy C++ code and have ran across references to boost::shared_static_cast but could not find a definition or much online help for it. I did find boost::static_pointer_cast which sounds similar.

Is boost::static_pointer_cast the replacement for boost::shared_static_cast ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Boost 1.52](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp) source code:

```
shared_*_cast names are deprecated. Use *_pointer_cast instead.
```

If you look carefully the source code, the implementations of `static_pointer_cast` and `shared_static_cast` were the same.

And there is no `shared_*_casts` since Boost 1.53.0.